# Error pyodbc Ubuntu

Tags: python, sql-server, linux, ubuntu, pyodbc

tengo un problema al intentar conectarme a una base de datos SQL Server a través de Python en Ubuntu usando pyodbc.

Al ejecutar, me aparece el siguiente error:

```
pyodbc.Error: ('01000', "[01000] [unixODBC][Driver Manager]Can't open lib 'SQL Server' : file not found (0) (SQLDriverConnect)")
```

Este es mi código:

```
conn = pyodbc.connect('Driver={SQL Server};'
                      'Server=SRV-NAME;'
                      'Database=DB-NAME;'
                      'Trusted_Connection=yes;'
                      'UID=USER;'
                      'PWD=PASSWD;')

cursor = conn.cursor()
cursor.execute('SELECT * FROM TABLE-NAME')
```

Alguien sabe como puedo solucionarlo?

Gracias de antemano.

Answer (score 0):

El problema es que estas usando el `Driver` que utiliza *Windows*, lo único que tienes que hacer es cambiar la linea:

`'Driver={SQL Server};'` por `'DRIVER={/opt/microsoft/msodbcsql17/lib64/libmsodbcsql-17.2.so.0.1};'`.

Comment: Esto ya lo he probé y no me funciona, aunque yo tengo la versión 17.3, utilizo ubuntu 19.04, no se si puede tener incompatibilidades. gracias